# w[warning]No test result files were found azure devops

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, testing, continuous-integration

I have created a simple .net core web app with sample unit test cases and build CI/CD using azure devops. My test cases are always returning true and I have tried executing them through visual studio as well. Please see below my Unit test case class.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace UnitTestProject1
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            Assert.IsTrue(true);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod2()
        {
            Assert.IsTrue(true);
        }
    }
}
```

I have used azure repository as git and created pipeline for CI. But when the test step of the pipeline is executed I get "[warning]No test result files were found" warning in the logs and my test cases are not executed. I have attached snip of test step in CI pipeline. Please suggest what is wrong here.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Remove the '1', rename your `UnitTest1` class to `UnitTests`. Make sure all your unit test class names end with `Tests`. But only on the class names, your test methods can have any name you want.